# Not doing anything for the first time running the function in javascript /jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, if-statement

The problem is I need to break the function if it is first time running
is there any function available , or I have to do something like the following?

```
var times = 1

function abc () {
    if (times == 1)
      break;
    else
      .....
    times++;
} 

times = 0;
```

Thanks.

Comment: `break` will cancel `for`, `while`, `do-while` and `switch` statements, but not a *function*. Use `return` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you're trying to solve the problem in the wrong place. Can you tell us the whole story?

In the meantime, something like this should do the trick:

```
function abc() {
    abc = function() {
         // ...actual work...
    }
}
```

Details depend on how your function is defined (globally, locally, as a method).

Comment: This is the best pattern in this case.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Mind explaining how it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern:

```
function abc() {

    if (!abc.flag) {
        abc.flag = true;
        return;
    }

    // .. rest of the code
}
```

It's based on the fact that Function is also an object in Javascript.

Basically this is a Memoization pattern. It has disadvantage that the `flag` property can be overwritten by another code. The advantage is that you don't need to pollute global scope with additional variables.

*thg435* proposed much more elegant solution.

Comment: OP - choose this answer! :)

Comment: @Jace No this is not the best answer. thg435 proposed proper method.

Comment: Where's thg435's solution?

Comment: @MarkBoulder It's georg now, changed username, I guess.

Comment: But how does placing a function inside another function make it not run the first time?

Comment: It's defined inside but not invoked. So after the first call `abc` redefines itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isFirstTime = true;

function abc () {
    if (isFirstTime)
    {
        isFirstTime = false;
        return;
    }
    .....
} 


abc(); //returns
abc(); //runs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var firstTime= true

    function abc () {
        if (firstTime)
        {
              firstTime = false;
              return;
        }

        else
        {
          .....
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
var times = 1;

function abc () {
if (times == 1){}     
else{
  .....
times == 0;}
}
```